# bxslider slide when a button is hovered

Tags: jquery, css

I am using bxslider. I have a anchor tag which is used to slide the bxslider. what i want is ..when i hover over the anchor tag(left and right) the slider should start scrolling horizontally in both direction and when i stop hovering the slider should stop scrolling.Any idea can help.

My anchor tag:

```
 <div class="positionSelectors">
  <a href="javascript:moveToPrev();">
    <img src="images/leftArrow.png"></img>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="positionSelectors">
  <a href="javascript:moveToNext();">
    <img src="images/rightArrow.png"></img>
  </a>
 </div>
```

Currently i am moving from one slide to next by following function :

```
function moveToNext() {
 buslider.goToNextSlide();
}
function moveToPrev() {
 buslider.goToPrevSlide();
}
```

Comment: how does a slider scroll in both direction at the same time?

Comment: The 4th dimension.

Comment: It will not scroll in both direction at same time. When left anchor tag hovered it will move towards left element and when right hovered it will move towards right slides @madalinivascu